# Monotouch command line build not working

Tags: .net, ios, build, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am trying to build a monotouch solution from the command line, it never goes past "Loading projects". The command just exits after that line.

Can anyone help?

```
MAC-2:IPadClient Chris$ /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool build -p IPadClient.sln 
    MonoDevelop Build Tool
    Loading solution: /Users/Chris/Dropbox/IPadClient/IPadClient.sln
       Loading solution: /Users/Chris/Dropbox/IPadClient/IPadClient.sln
          Loading projects .
```

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out, if the solution had already been built, it will not move past that step. Solution was to clean it first.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to omit the -p from your commandline.

`mdtool build` can optionally be provided the solution file (e.g. `mdtool build IPadClient.sln`), else it will just build the first solution it finds in the directory. The -p argument is for specifying the name of a particular project within the solution that you want to build, instead of building all projects in the solution.

So in your case it's loading the first solution it finds in the directory, trying to build a project called "IPadClient.sln", not finding it, and deciding it has nothing to do.